How do we write the Korean word for Korean Radish Soup (Mu Guk) in hangul?
What is the hangul for Korean radish soup (mu guk)?

무국
무= radish (mu)
국~= soup (guk)
generally, it makes with slide beef, we called 소고기무국.
소고기(sogogi) = beef
